# Android App uses too much memory. How can I make it run on less RAM?

Tags: android, debugging, ram

I built a simple app (TCHS JROTC) for Android phones and I am pretty decent at Android development. I built this app on a Galaxy S2 Epic 4g and it handled flawlessly. Except on other phones such as Evo 4g and Nexus S it force closes on one specific screen that has about 8 picture icons. I debug it and it throws out an error that says "Not Enough Memory" this is exactly what i thought it was because my code is pretty much flawless and works perfectly. Does anyone have ANY idea how to make an app maybe load incrementally instead of just dumping the Activity with the icon picture all at once? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, but your code is not flawless if it can't handle an out of memory error gracefully

Comment: Do you supply icons for different DPIs - i.e. do you define them for `drawable-xhdpi` / `drawable-hdpi` / `drawable-mdpi`  and `drawable-ldpi` - or did you just dump everything into `drawable`?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see log output at the point of the out of memory bug and also a deeper description of what you are doing on that screen. I'd verify that the images you use are size appropriately for your UI, using images larger than needed is a memory hog as they must be loaded in memory full size and then resized. Beyond that I'd guess you actually have a memory leak(s) and recommend you look up the Google IO video on using MAT.

Comment: Well i was using drawables and it was a very dumb mistake. i saved the pictures HUGE when they needed to be scaled small so when i rescaled them to the proper size my app went from 2MB to 567 or something KB! It fixed ALL force close issues and that was my problem. thanks for the help though !

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to reduce the memory consumption of your app is to use another encoding of pixels in your icons.

You can encode the pixels in RGB888, ARGB8888, ARGB4444, RGB565 and more i think. Here is how you can load Bitmaps if it is stored in the form of an asset. This example is from the book Beginning Android Games. Absolutely recomendable even if you are not interested in writing Android Games.

```
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("bob.png");
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

In this example ARGB4444 encoding is used. Which uses less memory than ARGB8888 for instance.

I am just a beginner in android programming. But i think it may also reduce the memory footprint of your app if you store the Images on the external memory/SD card instead of directly putting them into your project. This way they will be part of the resulting .apk file. Which will have some extra bytes. :-) Please correct me if i am wrong with this point. I am just learning.

Comment: Your last point is incorrect, storing files on a different file system location will not help out of memory (heap) issues.

Comment: Well i was using drawables and it was a very dumb mistake. i saved the pictures HUGE when they needed to be scaled small so when i rescaled them to the proper size my app went from 2MB to 567 or something KB! It fixed ALL force close issues and that was my problem. thanks for the help though !